# What is the formal definition for the format of an email address?

Tags: email, formal-languages

I would like to know the formal definition for the construction of an email address.

I don't just want the answer, but how to get to it, as I'd to learn how to do it myself.

Comment: see http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html Also, please don't use the homework tag, it's now obsolete... however, if this is homework, I really feel for you. the formal format of an email address is very complex, despite it looking simple

Comment: Ok, I just thought I'd add it since I have seen some flamewar from people who didn't.

This is meant to be quite simple, I think they are looking for just say, a word, then @, then domain name.

I am free to make any assumptions.

Comment: Well, what I'd consider the formal definition is something like this: http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/rfc/822addr.html

Answer (score 2):

Formal definition? See [RFC821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821#page-30).

```
<path> ::= "<" [ <a-d-l> ":" ] <mailbox> ">"
<a-d-l> ::= <at-domain> | <at-domain> "," <a-d-l> 
<at-domain> ::= "@" <domain>
<domain> ::=  <element> | <element> "." <domain>
<element> ::= <name> | "#" <number> | "[" <dotnum> "]"
<mailbox> ::= <local-part> "@" <domain>
<local-part> ::= <dot-string> | <quoted-string>
<name> ::= <a> <ldh-str> <let-dig>
<ldh-str> ::= <let-dig-hyp> | <let-dig-hyp> <ldh-str>
<let-dig> ::= <a> | <d>
<let-dig-hyp> ::= <a> | <d> | "-"
<dot-string> ::= <string> | <string> "." <dot-string>
<string> ::= <char> | <char> <string>
<quoted-string> ::=  """ <qtext> """
<qtext> ::=  "\" <x> | "\" <x> <qtext> | <q> | <q> <qtext>
<char> ::= <c> | "\" <x>
<dotnum> ::= <snum> "." <snum> "." <snum> "." <snum>
<number> ::= <d> | <d> <number>
<CRLF> ::= <CR> <LF>
```